# How do i get the location of a control with respect to other control

Tags: c#, .net, position, picturebox

Say i have two picture boxes which are overlapping each other as show below

[image]

How do i get the location of picture box 2 with respect to picturebox1 ?

Thanks In advance. :) :)

Comment: Generally these things involve a bit of Math. Use the Top and left properties in conjunction with height and width to determine distance. If you prefer you can call [DisplayRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.displayrectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) for both controls which might simplify some of the calculations.

Comment: I think using the [ClientArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the correct choice. - However you need to be sure about the relation between the 2 PBs: Are they both sitting on the Form and overlapping? Then you need to subtract their Locations. __Or__ is the 2nd one __inside__ the 1st one? (`pictureBox2.Parent = pictureBox1;`) In that case you need no Math, as its Location already is relative to the 1st one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to Screen coords and then back to Client coords like this:

```
        Rectangle PB2Screen = pictureBox2.RectangleToScreen(pictureBox2.ClientRectangle);
        Rectangle PB2RelativeToPB1 = pictureBox1.RectangleToClient(PB2Screen);
        Console.WriteLine("pictureBox2 Location Relative to pictureBox1: " + PB2RelativeToPB1.Location.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("PB2RelativeToPB1: " + PB2RelativeToPB1.ToString());
```